# Close gap between timestamps in a collection after deleting items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of items which have a timestamp property.

Now I want to delete a bulk of those items from somewhere in the middle and then close the time gap that is left by subtracting the removed timespan from all timestamps that come after the gap.
In addition, I want to enable the user to choose how large (in seconds) the gap should be.

How should I go about this? I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: _"close the time gap that is left by subtracting the removed timespan from all timestamps that come after the gap"_ Could you explain this further, maybe with sample data? How can i "close a gap" in a collection?

Comment: Define "gap". For instance, when two items are 1 ms apart, is that a gap? Underlying question: can you recognize a gap after items were deleted, not knowing these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need linq; in fact it's easier for me to explain it without.

Make a second collection to represent your gap. Iterate over the source collection, and where the timestamp lies within your gap add the items to the second collection. Then, since you're iterating anyway, where the timestamp lies beyond your gap, subtract your gap length from it.

Then, iterate over your second temporary collection and for each item remove it from your primary collection. Longwinded but you can't remove items from a collection while you're iterating over it.